# Sales Prediction

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, regression, random-forest

I want to predict sales quantity for items. My data is like if the item is sold in week it has number of items sold. **If not sold sales quantity is maintained as zero. Problem is my data is having lot of unsold records compared to sold items. Is it okay to maintain zero sales record in training data?**
Currently I am using **Random Forest** for  my prediction.

Comment: Try Poisson regression, keeping the zero counts.